# Simple I/O manipulator not working as intended

Tags: c++, io

the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

std::ios_base &my_manip (std::basic_ios<char> &os) {
    os.unsetf(std::ios_base::basefield);
    os.setf(std::ios_base::scientific);
    return os;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << 8.8888888 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_manip << 8.8888888 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
8.88889

18.88889
```

While the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

std::ios_base &my_manip (std::basic_ios<char> &os) {
    os.unsetf(std::ios_base::basefield);
    os.setf(std::ios_base::scientific);
    return os;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << 8.8888888 << std::endl;
    my_manip(std::cout);
    std::cout << 8.8888888 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints the expected result:

```
8.88889

8.888889e+00
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the first version?

Comment: `basic_ostream` has overloads for function pointers. The signature of your function doesn't match any of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The custom manipulator signature is not matching,

You should be doing this :

```
std::ostream& my_manip (std::ostream &os) {
    os.unsetf(std::ios_base::basefield);
    os.setf(std::ios_base::scientific);
    return os;
}

std::cout << my_manip << 8.8888888 << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three overloads taking a function pointer which can be used for manipulators. The three signatures are

```
std::ios_base&                  (*)(std::ios_base&)
std::basic_ios<cT, Traits>&     (*)(std::basic_ios<cT, Traits>&);
std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>&);
```

The signature you used (`std::ios_base&(*)(std::basic_ios<cT, Traits>&)`) is none of these.

I assume you are using the actual settings as examples because the `std::scientific` manipulator already implements the logic your example code tries to implement.

Comment: I'd expect a compiler error. Do you happen to know why it there isn't one?

Comment: @jrok: a pointer to function converts to `bool` and since there is no matching output operator for the type `std::ios_base&(*)(std::basic_ios<cT, Traits>&)` the pointer to function converts to `bool` (actually `true`) as there is an output operator for `bool`. The value `true` is printed as `1` (use `std::boolalpha` if you want to see it printed as `true` instead...).

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the signature of your manipulator. If you change it to

```
std::basic_ostream<char> &my_manip (std::basic_ostream<char> &os)
```

then it works as you expect it to.